# android broadcast receiver and dual SIM

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I have developed an app that has a receiver for incoming call, it works fine for all phones. One user has a dual SIM android phone. The app works fine for the first SIM. But when someone calls on his second SIM, our app is not invoked.

Can someone please guide, what is wrong, or is there some limitation in Android ?

Answer (score 1):

Any application  built on Android will guarantee only for Single SIM mobiles. Because Android does not support multiple SIMs, at least from the SDK. Device manufacturers who have created multi-SIM devices are doing so on their own. You are welcome to contact your device manufacturer and see if they have an SDK add-on or something that allows you to access the second SIM.

Comment: @user835791- You should always accept a correct answer as it could help others who has a similar problem and check this question !!!

Comment: Nilay I don't think your answer is correct. There are many apps in the market which is providing call logs for dual sim as well and i don't think that they go to each manufacturer for this. There is something which we are missing here. Check this app..https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.softrelay.calllog